# 'Permission denied' executing 'ls -l' against cifs share on Fedora 39

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, samba, windows-server-2016, fedora

Setup:

1. Windows Server 2016, workgroup mode, a shared folder 'SHARE' with username/password security, owned by BUILTIN\Everyone.
2. Fedora 39, everything updated to the latest versions.
3. etc/fstab:

```
//server/share /var/spool/share cifs username=user1,password=password1 0 0
```

4. automount works just fine, no errors anywhere, r/w access works with no issues
5. *ls /var/spool/share* works with no issues
6. *ls -l /var/spool/share* prints an error yet nevertheless displays the content of the folder

```
root@fedora:~# ls -l /var/spool/share/
ls: /var/spool/share/: Permission denied
```

7. *ls -laX* prints two errors but still displays the content

```
root@fedora:~# ls -laX /var/spool/share/
ls: /var/spool/share/: Permission denied
ls: /var/spool/share/.: Permission denied
```

8. *strace ls -la /var/spool/share* shows 'Permission denied' on **listxattr** call(s).

Same setup, Fedora replaced with Ubuntu 22 - no 'Permission denied' messages.

Any help getting to the bottom of this 'Permission denied' thing is deeply appreciated.

Comment: What ls the output of ls -ld /var/spool/share/ (also use the d flag)?

Comment: 'Permission denied' message and then normal 'ls -ld' output.

Comment: What ls the output of ls -ld /var/spool/* ?

Comment: 'ls: /var/spool/share: Permission denied' and then normal output again:
`drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 32768 Mar  5 20:22 /var/spool/share`